Postgresql with docker: Legacy DB name keeps coming up in logs
I create a docker container for postgres with a docker-compose file as:
version: '3.8'

services:
  lidardata:
    image: pgpointcloud/pointcloud
    container_name: lidar-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: Lidar
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

As can be seen, db name is 'Lidar'. And it works all fine.
Problem is that in one of previous version of this, I used db name as 'lidar'. And this name is stuck somewhere in overall setup, and as a result logs keep showing:
FATAL:  database "lidar" does not exist

I cleaned up volume, removed older images and containers, but this keeps showing up.
What sort of cleanup would get rid of it?

check your volume: postgres_data, may be delete it too.

I deleted it too, but didn't help.

Maybe some parts of your system use double-quoted identifiers and some don't. In that case, every unquoted Lidar gets folded to lowercase lidar, causing the error (the message will quote the folded identifier even if the issuer used unquoted mixed case) Some tools can be configured to add double quotes automatically.

demo
